# Django: counting M2MField of an M2MField?

Tags: django

I have models as follows:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)  
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300) 
class Manor(models.Model):
    place = models.ManyToManyField(Place, related_name="place"))  
    lord = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name="lord")  
    overlord = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name="overlord")
```

If I do `{{ person.lord.count }}` in my template, I can get the count of the Manors attached to each Person.

Is there a way I can do an equivalent of `{{ person.lord.place.count }}` (which doesn't work), to get the count of the Places attached to the Manors attached to each Person?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sum([lord.place.count() for lord in person.lords.all()])
```